# Way to sync changes from LocalCollection to the Server

Tags: meteor

Is anybody knows how to sync local changes with server collection in Meteor. I have

```
MyCollection._collection.insert({});
MyCollection._collection.update({});
// etc
```

So I want sync that changes as I use simply MyCollection.insert

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're doing this? Why not use MyCollection.insert directly? You could loop through each one and send it to the server via a method and it would be synced back down.

Comment: I have a lot of local manipulations on a client. LocalCollection works fine for me and it could be a reactive source for DOM rendering. I.e. I used that as a client-side models. So at the moment all changes are done I just want to sync changes

Answer (score 0):

I made a proof of concept earlier for what you describe. Its not finished but should be of some help:

https://gist.github.com/marcodejongh/c2056ab5b5f7a360cb0a

If the route is called with a  _id it copies the document from the collection to the local collection. If _id is not specified it should create a new document in the actual collection then go to the route with the new _id (that part of my poc is not working yet)

The changed helper compares the actual collection with the local collection so it can warn the user before writing over someone elses changes.

Note: I hardcoded my itemid because I had a problem with my router change that to parameter in your route

Comment: Got it! I tryed this way - it is not the one I want to implement. You use unnamed collection - in this way if have collection named Posts and you want to inerate its local records and server recordset you have to inerate and stick data from original Post collection and Unnamed